# Inject service into controller in Symfony 2.8?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.8

I'm really struggling to try to inject a service into a controller, I found some post and this is what I have tried:

I have a service called FormatService

```yaml
services:
    formats_service:
            class: FormatsBundle\Services\FormatService
```

I want it to be injected into `FormatsController` so I tried [Defining Controllers as Services](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/controller/service.html), then changed my entire routing as the docs states

```
app.formats_controller:
        class: ABundle\Controller\FormatsController
        arguments: ["@formats_service"]
```

Doing this gives me an `Error: Call to a member function has() on null` error when I try to access to
any endpoint from my control

Then I tried to gather it from the container doing something like this

```php
public function __construct () {
  $this->formatService = $this->container->get('formats_service');
}
```

This gives me an error, `$this->container` seems to be null.

I did a research and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711482/this-container-is-null-in-controller-on-symfony3) INJECT the container to my controller but the solution is the same thing I couldn't accomplish from the 1st point, I cant inject services since to do so I need to define my controller as a service but doing so gives me `Error: Call to a member function has() on null` whenever I try to access to any endpoint from my controller

Is there any way to inject a service into a controller without doing an entire mess in Symfony 2.8?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer in the link you posted.  See that part about calls? That is known as setter injection.  In a Symfony controller the container is not injected into the constructor but rather via a setContainer method.  Add the calls stuff to your service definition and you should be okay.  Having said that, for 2.8 defining controllers as services was not the standard.  You can go back to your old route style and just use $this->get('my_service')

Comment: But just to clarify, $this->get() goes inside an action method.  Not the constructor.  The container is not available in the constructor.

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message. Which line of code throws that error?

Comment: @NicoHaase I already solved it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the controller you don't need to declare it as a service because the controller have the **container** you can use  **php app/console debug:container** to see if your service is in your container and you can use it directy into your actions

```
public function newAction()
```

{

```
// the container will instantiate a new FormatService()
$myService = $this->container->get('formats_service');
```

}

you can see more here https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html

Comment: Your solution applies to a typical controller that extends the base `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` which is container aware. The question asks for "controller as a service" which typically is not container-aware and does not extend that base controller.

Comment: You are absoluty right i taught he was over doing it and he was using the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller

Comment: Even if this works, it should not be used, as injecting the container itself is not a good style. Inject the exact services you need instead

Comment: @NicoHaase - Remember that this is a 2.8 app.  Back then controllers were not routinely defined as services and the container was used as a service locator.  Injecting the container is the best practice for a 2.8 app legacy app.

Answer (score 3):

When defining a controller as a service you have to inject the services directly without accessing the container. You can have a mixed approach when your controller extends Symfony's base controller, but it is usually discouraged.

It should work if you modify your controller's constructor:

```php
public function __construct(FormatsBundle\Services\FormatService $formatService) 
{
    $this->formatService = $formatService;
}
```

edit: If you want to use the container in your controller you should either extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` or add `use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait`, but again both is discouraged when using controllers as a service, because then you could just as well write a regular controller.

Comment: Well no.  You use setter injection to inject the container.  And this is 2.8.  Way before autowire was even considered.

Comment: In the question there is a service configuration for the required service and for injecting it as argument to the controller service, or am I missing something? With the service configuration as provided by the question my answer should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is one of those not uncommon cases where the person posting the questions did not understand what question they were actually asking.  The problem started when they attempted to use $this->get in a controller's constructor.  The call fails because the container is not yet available.  They then went down the rabbit trail of attempting to define the controller as a service overlooking the step in which setContainer needs to be called in the service definition.  You made the assumption that the base Controller class was not being used when in fact it is.

Comment: The real question was why $this->get failed in the constructor.  And the solution was to simply move it into the action method.